# Kendo Ui grid: Popup window Add trigger from outside grid

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the grid and button below. What i am trying to achieve is to trigger Kendoui popup window when is the btnAdd clicked. I am aware that this can be achieve if you put button in kendo ui grid toolbar.

Please advise, thank you

```
    <script>      
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {               

        });
     </script>        

     <input type="button" id="btnAdd"/>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PWeb_App.ViewModels.ResultModel>()        
            .Name("Result")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10px; width:985px" })               
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.GivenName).Width(90);
                columns.Bound(p => p.FamilyName).Width(90);       
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Save())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
            .Sortable()        
            .Pageable(paging => paging
                .Input(false)
                .Numeric(true)        
                .PreviousNext(true)
                .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50 })
                .Refresh(false)        
            )        
            .Selectable()
            .Scrollable()
            .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
                .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
                .PageSize(10)
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.Pid);
                        model.Field(p => p.FamilyName).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(p => p.GivenName).Editable(false);        
                    })
                   .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Details").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                            .Update("Edit", "Details")

                )

        )
```

Comment: Shouldn't your button-script include a few lines of js for that to work outside the grid..?

Answer (score 5):

You can use grid [add row](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-addRow) api call to trigger add-popup as:

```
<script>
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        grid = $("#Result").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am trying using popup not incell. Thank you

Comment: What i am trying to say is, just remove .Save() from toolbar for our popup to bubble up, otherwise error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

maybe adding the    editable : "popup" will solve your problem?

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) .